# Youtube API Playlist shuffle

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

the homepage of [www.rupertlaycock.com](http://www.rupertlaycock.com) has a div called bgvid. It's a full screen youtube player that is supposed to play a random video from my playlist. However the code I have fails on first load in any browser, 1-3 refreshes fixes it though and I cannot figure out why.

Here's the existing code

```html
<script>
    // Load the YouTube iFrame API asynchronously
    const tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // YouTube player settings
    let player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('bgvid', {
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            videoId: '', // This will be set dynamically
            playerVars: {
                autoplay: 1,
                controls: 0,
                modestbranding: 1,
                loop: 1,
                playlist: '', // This will be set dynamically
                enablejsapi: 1,
                fs: 0,
                showinfo: 0,
                autohide: 1,
                rel: 0,
                cc_load_policy: 0,
                iv_load_policy: 3,
                disablekb: 1,
                mute: 1 // Set the video to mute
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        // Replace 'YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID' with your actual YouTube playlist ID
        const playlistId = 'PLBxa5RWLF0lWmqWYGFD8pZy6DHlmf4xU7';

        // Fetch playlist items and shuffle them
        fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=${playlistId}&key=AIzaSyC...`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                const items = data.items;
                shuffle(items);

                // Extract video IDs from playlist items
                const videoIds = items.map(item => item.snippet.resourceId.videoId);

                // Set the playlist and load a random video
                player.loadPlaylist(videoIds);
                const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * videoIds.length);
                player.playVideoAt(randomIndex);
            });
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        // Handle video state changes here if needed
    }

    // Shuffle array function
    function shuffle(array) {
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
        }
    }
</script>
```

I've gone around and around in circles with ChatGPT as i'm no script expert.

Comment: Thanks Yogi, can you please show me what part of code is redundant? I'm still very much learning and cobbled this together with other users codes...

As for the replication, it tends to work least in safari and on iOS devices on first load. However, if the device is refreshed it works fine. Unfortunately a potential client wouldn't be hitting refresh...